# Zend_Form from ini, set multiOptions with string values

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to configure a form for Zend_Form using Zend_Config_Ini, and wish to set the options for a select element in the .ini file.

This works fine for options with single string values, i.e.

```
user.exampleform.elements.subject.options.multiOptions.example = "Example Label"
```

However, I can't work out how to use a string for the value, i.e. "example choice"

I'm using Zend Framework 1.9.3PL1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of [`Zend_Form_Element_Multi::addMultiOptions`](http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/~raw,r=9409/Zend_Framework/trunk/library/Zend/Form/Element/Multi.php)

```
user.exampleform.elements.subject.options.multiOptions.example.key = "Example Choice"
user.exampleform.elements.subject.options.multiOptions.example.value = "Example Label"
```

Comment: Great, thanks - I've been turning to checking the element and helper source, as information such as this wasn't present in the documentation.